# flag node when clicking on a link in a view (not a flag link)

Tags: views, navigation, flags

I have a view which displays nodes information on a table, each row is a node, in each row I have two links, one opens a node file field in a new window, the other one open a colorbox showing the node body.
I would like to flag the node when the user clicks on any of these two link, but I  can't figure how Ican do this.
Any hint much appreciated.
Thank you.